# javascript RegEx to support Aruba and Barbados zip code

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking for a regex to allow below 2 zip codes for Aruba and Barbados

```
 - Aruba - 0000AW  (Only 6 characters are allowed in the format 4
   digit(only 0) at the beginning and 2 characters (only A and W) at the
   end )

 - Barbados - BB15094 (Only 7 characters are allowed in the format 2
   characters(only B) at the beginning and 4 digits (0 t0 9) at the end)
```

Can somebody please help me to get the regex for this ?

I guess Barbados - `/^[Bb]{2}?[0-9]{5}$/` and Aruba - `/^[0]{4}?[Aa]{1}[Ww]{1}$/`.

Comment: 30 minutes [spent here](https://regexone.com/) will teach you how to write it in no time.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for thids link.
For Barbados i tried /^[Bb][Bb]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ and it works . However i don't want to repeat [0-9] for 5 times. Could you please help ?

Comment: You missed [*Lesson 6: Catching some zzz's*](https://regexone.com/lesson/repeating_characters).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Got it i guess
Barbados - /^[Bb]{2}?[0-9]{5}$/ 
Aruba - /^[0]{4}?[Aa]{1}[Ww]{1}$/
Could you please verify once ?

Comment: Aruba regex is funny. 1) `/^b{2}\d{5}$/i` 2) `/^0{4}aw$/i`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will use the regex suggested by you ..
You made me learn something new today.Thanks

Comment: Post them with explanations to get some points.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew One clarification . You have used i for case insensitive.
But when i am using your regex in https://regex101.com/ for testing it doesn't work.
Could you please help ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141961/discussion-between-kenta-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Either post your answer, or please consider accepting mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the "cleaner" versions of your regexes:

Barbados ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/RBT0e6/1)):

```
/^b{2}\d{5}$/i
```

[Aruba](https://regex101.com/r/aphsq2/1):

```
/^0{4}aw$/i
```

Note the case insensitive modifier `/i` allowing to reduce `[aA]` to `a`, etc.
You do not need to enclose *single* chars into character classes, `[0]` = `0`. It makes no sense using a lazy limiting quantifier with an exact number of occurrences, `{4}?` = `{4}`. The `{1}` quantifier is by default redundant, since all atoms match a single occurrence by default (`\d[a-z]` matches a single digit followed with a single lowercase ASCII letter).

Note that in JS regex, `\d` is equal to `[0-9]`.